# How to use $value using Microsoft Graph library in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to receive some .eml attachments from some emails.
Based on the documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message I need to use: GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value

The problem here is that I don't know how to do this using Microsoft.Graph library in C#.
I don't know to append that "$value" to the call. Below I have attached the C# structure that I am currently using to get attachments for a specific email. Any advice could help. Thanks.

```
return await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages[emailId].Attachments.Request().GetAsync()
```

Comment: What is your current request returning?

Comment: It is returning a list of ItemAttachment. For a better understanding, if i have a .jpg file attachment in the email, Microsoft graph returns a FileAttachment type, but for .eml attachment it returns an ItemAttachment. I need the stream for the .eml files to be saved somewhere and use it to recreate the .eml file when it is needed.

Comment: It appears there is one more step for getting the contents of an ItemAttachment see documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-2

Comment: Ok, thank you. This could help. But still not available to create the .eml file. Any idea?

Comment: Or maybe how to get MIME content?

Comment: I see where the .eml can be attached to a message https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp but as far as saving it somewhere else I really don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK doesn't currently support this in a straight-forward manner. Typically to get the `/$value` segment appended to the generated request URL, you access a `Content` property on the request builder. The problem is that the generic `IAttachmentRequestBuilder` doesn't implement this property, only the `FileAttachmentRequestBuilder` does.

So to get this to work with the current SDK, you need to do it like this:

```cs
var msgId = "message-id";
var attId = "attachment-id";

var attachmentRequestBuilder = client.Me.Messages[msgId].Attachments[attId];
var fileRequestBuilder = new FileAttachmentRequestBuilder(
    attachmentRequestBuilder.RequestUrl, client);

Console.WriteLine($"Request URL: {fileRequestBuilder.Content.Request().RequestUrl}");
var stream = await fileRequestBuilder.Content.Request().GetAsync();

using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attachment contents:");
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

I've let the SDK folks know about this.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah this definitely works. Just heads up, if you want to quickly parse the MIME message to for example retrieve other parts such as any attachments I found this library useful: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKitLite